# How can I add mongoDB service on windows startup?

Tags: windows, mongodb, startup

I am trying to add mongoDB service on windows startup but still I am not able to do it.

Every time i have to start mongoDB service manually.

I have looked into how to add application on startup in windows but it only starts application not service like this

[image]

So can you help me to find solution to add mongoDB service to startup in windows so it can automatically starts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services` you can find the `MongoDB Database Server` service and change it's `Startup Type` to `Automatic`.

If no `MongoDB Database Server` service is listed in the services,  you need to install it as `MongoDB as a Windows service` as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

Comment: Windows key + r and type 'services'.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the MongoDB Server is enabled on the windows services list. You can verify by opening the Run application `Windows Key + R` and execute the command `msconfig`. This will open a window, where you can navigate to services and verify if the MongoDB Server box is enabled.

[image].

Comment: It is enabled @Renan Lopes